# Did not find storyboard referenced from Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 7.1 and I am using storyboard references to go to different storyboards. The problem is everytime I run the simulator, there is an error that says, `"Did not find storyboard named "Storyboard" referenced from Main.storyboard"`. But the storyboard reference is set to go to `"Storyboard"`. So I need some help. Thanks in advance!

Here is my view.

[image]

Comment: You should accept the answer if that was the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have set the Storyboard Id in the right side bar. It should be the same value as you reference it.

[image]

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that it helped

Comment: @MKoosej which storyboard I need to check ? whether Main.storyboard or Refactor storyboard? I checked it but I got the above error.Can you please give me an idea?

Answer (score 33):

This problem can also arise if you have somehow managed to ***uncheck*** the Target and you are running the project for that Target. Make sure you have ***checked*** all the targets you want to run the project on.

[image: Check your file inspector]

Comment: Ran into a similiar issue earlier this week only with code files. Same thing happened when duplicating the storyboard file too. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome :) Its pretty simple but yeah you can just miss it sometimes..

Comment: As of Xcode 9, this issue can show up when refactoring Storyboards. Funny thing is that refactoring worked well for the first few scenes. When I was refactoring the 6th or 7th time (from a massive all scenes in one storyboard type) it started throwing linker errors. So I assumed I did some mistake. Thanks for this answer Bhavik!

Answer (score 5):

Only removing localization from storyboard file helped me. (Delete storyboard file from project and add again)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to add my project target as the target membership of the storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when the one storyboard was using "Base" localization and the other "English". They need to match up or you will get linker errors.

Answer (score 1):

For me the refactored Storyboard was missing from Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. Adding it manually fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had refactored a storyboard, extracting one scene to another storyboard. That storyboard wasn't in the Copy Bundle Resources. I hadn't quite gotten to the point of tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

**XCODE 12.2**

this error happened for several issues, so **check the following checklist**:

1 - define the initial view controller in the destination storyboard or check the storyboard id that you put is the same as the storyboard id in the destination storyboard.

2 - the destination storyboard target memberships must include all targets that checked on the first storyboard.

3- check all the localization in the destination and the first storyboard are the same.
[image]