# Did not find view controller with identifier "Home" in Home.storyboard, referenced from Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]
[image]

This is my setup. I have "Home.storyboard" in the same directory as the "Main.storyboard" that is shown in the images.

The error I get is:

(null): Did not find view controller with identifier "Home" in Home.storyboard, referenced from Main.storyboard

›I have made sure to set the Storyboard Id in the right side bar. It has the same value as the reference ID. From: [Did not find storyboard referenced from Main.storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379109/did-not-find-storyboard-referenced-from-main-storyboard/33380392#33380392)

Note also that my storyboards are "localized" which some of the other answers suggest. They are all in the same directory.

What am I missing? How am I assigning this wrong?

Edit: Note that my Home.storyboard is being built as part of the target
[image]

Comment: Make sure that `Home` storyboard is member of your target (File inspector > Target Membership)

Comment: @Alladinian thanks good suggestion. It still cannot find it. Are my Storyboard Reference, Storyboard ID, and Reference ID all supposed to be set to "Home" like I have shown in the pictures?

Comment: @Alladinian note that this changed the error message to: 
(null): Did not find view controller with identifier "Home" in Home.storyboard, referenced from Main.storyboard

Comment: Then your storyboard is now found, you just have to pass the same *controller* reference (the storyboard id of your referenced controller on `Home` should match the one on `Main`'s proxy)

Comment: @Alladinian ok I set the storyboard ID to "Home" on the Home View Controller, since it is set to "Home" on the main proxy. Should I also set the restoration ID and check the "use storyboard ID" box?

Comment: No, restoration id is irrelevant in your case. The idea is that you must provide the Storyboard that you reference (`Storyboard` field) and then which controller of this storyboard (`Referenced ID`) you like to connect. If I recall correctly you can leave it blank and it will reference the initial controller of the storyboard as well. So this proxy object is always pointing to a _controller_ not to a storyboard... I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: @Alladinian ok thanks. So I did't set the restoration ID and I didn't check the "use storyboard ID" box, but I did set the storyboard ID to "Home". Now it builds! But it crashes immediately with : SweatNet[688:178250] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SweatNet.HomeViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107dfbaf0'

Comment: Great to hear that. What the crash tells you now is that you tried to send a message (collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:) to an object (HomeViewController) that doesn't implement such a method...