# Facing issues with compiling storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am facing issues in compiling storyboards, i just created a new project,
steps:

1: created single view application
2: clicked run button

Now you can see the errors that Xcode gives me by clicking following image URLs:

[image: storyboard UI]

[image: storyboard error]

Comment: If you showed the actual error there may be a chance someone can help you out...

Comment: You can see the errors by clicking the image urls

Comment: ok, yep - missed the stack trace png. 
So the error is that you have not set the storyboard correctly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379109/did-not-find-storyboard-referenced-from-main-storyboard

Comment: Ok i'll try the storyboard issue but what about the pod related issue?

Comment: I just tried and it works fine: 

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworkActivityLogger (3.0.0)
Using AFNetworking (3.0.4)
Installing AWSCore (2.8.1)
Installing AWSS3 (2.8.1)

Maybe try to update cocoa pods: 
[sudo] gem install cocoapods

Comment: I've already tried updating cocoa pods before but it gives me same error, still i'll try installing pods with specific versions that you have mentioned, thanks

Comment: can you check your Ruby version, eg from command line: ruby -v

Comment: My ruby version is 2.3.7 ruby gem is 2.5.3.2, all the information is provided in the images, just read the question and the images carefully

Comment: can you just have a look at storyboard issue, leave the pod issue

Comment: try a new project

Comment: I already tried @ktrkathir